# Activity diagram optional flows (OR logic)

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

This question can be a basic one. But I could not find an answer by googling or searching in the SO.

I have a user who can perform three actions.

- View dashboard
- View reports
- Create users

When the user logs in to the system he can do one or more tasks from the above list in any order before he logs out.

Some examples:

1. View dashboard -> View reports -> View dashboard -> Logout
2. View dashboard -> View reports -> Create user -> View report -> Create user -> View dashboard -> Logout

Can I cover all the possible combinations simply by adding a fork and a join as below? Or what is the general practice to sketch this kind of situation. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not correct. The fork/join create a parallel flow. That means all three actions must be taken and finished until the Logout can take place.

It's a bit tricky to draw these conditions:

[image]

The `A/B/C possible` guards let you choose once any action. I abbreviated that in the drawing but you can simply add a note to the diagram explaining that. Or if you dare you can write some OCL. Same for the `Logout` which can only be taken one of the other actions have run once. There's a simple loop so you can select each action one after the other.